# Turned away from hospitals

Tags: uae

I am an Indian with a history of psychosis living in the United Arab Emirates. During one of my psychoses, I was turned away by 2 mental hospitals in this country. I dont think 2 hospitals in the country would have lack of space. Hospitals turning away patients seems ridiculous to me. Is this due to discrimination against expatriates or simply because there was nothing they could do once I was in active psychosis?

Comment: Did they provide any explanation on why they refused to take you?

Comment: they just told my family there was nothing they could do for me. I was not conscious but being very aggressive and violent which is to be expected under psychosis. the least they could have done would be to sedate me.

Comment: Not all mental health facilities are equipped to deal with violent patients.

Comment: i can understand if they didn't have beds. but not even enough attention for sedation?

Comment: This is why I always travel with two ziplock bags full of medication. Anything happens, I'm going to be ready for it.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS You need to have presence of mind to take it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this properly, you should consult with a medical professional.  Your diagnosing doctor should be able to tell you whether a hospital can do anything for you when you are in psychosis.  They should also be able to advise you on the specific steps you should take when you are actively having an attack.

As for discrimination, while it may be the case, as long as you are choosing to live there you are going to have to find a way around it.  Perhaps others in the expat or Indian communities can tell you where they have had successful services rendered.